# laravel5 eloquent foreign key hasOne()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, eloquent

I've got a transaction table containing the data of **transactions** like: `id|user_id|amount|payment_method_id|...`

The **payment_methods** table contains the different payment methods. Table design is: `id|name`

Content of the table is like:

1|paypal

2|credit card.

Now I would like to display a transaction history. This works fine but laravel always displays the number of the payment method, not the name. My transaction model looks like:

```
public function payment_method_id()
 {
  return $this->hasOne('App\Payment_Method', 'id', 'tpayment_method_id');
 }
```

All the time it displays the number, but not the correct name of payment method. Where's my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define relationship this way:

```
public function paymentMethod()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Payment_Method', 'payment_method_id');
}
```

And now you can display payment method name this way:

```
echo $transaction->paymentMethod->name;
```

In your example you used the same name of relationship as column and you used `hasOne` relationship instead of `belongsTo`

Comment: This is a good answer. Naming the method with id in it is not a good idea. You are returning the entire PaymentMethod object and hence naming the relationship appropriately will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an `Transaction` model containing `payment_method_id()` method that define the relationship between `transaction` and `payment method` tables. Now, you can access all `columns/property` from any transaction object. It should be something like followings:

`$transection->payment_method_id->name;`